# how to modify htaccess to manage request for codeigniter as well as wordpress

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have installed CodeIgniter in the root folder. Now i want to install wordpress along with it. I installed wordpress in a folder named blog.
If i type the url www.example.com/blog then i can see the home page of the wordpress blog. but if i click on the article then i got to land inside the codeigniter saying the page does not found.

I have witten the below in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Please tell me how to proceed. Do i have to modify htaccess or have to route the request from the route file in codeigniter.

Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745709/integrating-wordpress-codeigniter-htaccess

Comment: use `RewriteCond $1 !^(blog|index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)` instead.

Comment: This also did not solve. I want that when example.com/(blog is not here) then index.php/(something). Here index.php is inserted in between. but in the case of example.com/blog it should go to example.com/blog/index.php.